# Defining a cost function to find a rotation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, reference-request, optimization

Suppose I have pairs of vector $\left\{(v_i,w_i)\right\}_{1 \leq i \leq n}$, and I want to find an angle $\theta$ that describes an optimal rotation that aligns all the pairs.

Now two possible cost functions came to my mind the first one is

$$
C_1(\theta) = \frac{1}{2n} \sum_i (\theta - \theta_i)^2
$$

where $\theta_i$ is the angle between $v_i$ and $w_i$.
On the other end however since $\left\langle v_i,w_i \right\rangle = \left\lVert v_i \right\rVert \left\lVert w_i \right\rVert \cos \theta_i$

Clearly the two vectors are aligned if $\cos \theta_i = 1$ therefore I was thinking of minimizing

$$
C_2(\theta) = \frac{1}{2n} \sum_i \left(1 - \cos \left( \theta -\theta_i\right) \right)^2
$$

For both functions I'd assume all the angles, including the unknown are in the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$.

It is clear that if there's a perfect rigid transformations the solution would be the same for both cases, however in general which one is better?

Is there a known similar problem that uses $C_2$ instead of something like $C_1$?

Computationally speaking $C_1$ has a closed form solution

(Assume you have many many pairs $(v_i,w_i)$...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C_1$ has a closed form if you know the angles $\theta_i$ ,your vectors are in $2d$and don't have issues with $2\pi$ type ambiguities. As for C_$2$ which is more standard, [try this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem)

Comment: Interesting, how is my $C_2$ related to the wikipage? I don't see the same formula, is there a specific one you can point out just for sake of comparison?

Comment: By the way, in theory in my case $\theta_i$'s are known in my problem, I can easily retrieve them.

Comment: treat the vectors $v_i$ as the columns of $A$ and $u_i$ as the columns of$B$ ( as used in the wiki article). Applying a single rotation matrix $\Omega$ on the $v$'s now  becomes $\Omega \{ v_1,\cdots v_n\}=\Omega A$  and the square of all the distances  $\sum |\Omega v_i-u_i|^2$  is $|\Omega A-B|^2$

Comment: Though I understand the formula, I struggle a bit to see the resemblance with mine, am I supposed to be able to derive my $C_2$ from $\sum |\Omega v_i - u_i|^2$?

Comment: $v_i \cdot u_i= |v||u|\cos\theta_i$ so $\Omega v_i \cdot u_i=|v||u|\cos(\theta_i -\theta_\Omega)$

Comment: Where would the $1 - ...$ come from?

Comment: its just a constant, shouldnt affect the cost